# How to override a function in parent WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a child theme using [Flaxseed](https://wordpress.org/themes/flaxseed-pro/) as a parent. This theme includes several 'content styles' which can be selected using Theme > Customizer. Each of these styles has a function in the parent functions.php file that renders the CSS and wordpress content into one. I want to edit some of the Loop functions that are in here, specifically updating the_excerpt to the_content, but I want to do so in a way that works with my child theme.

Since this code is in the parent functions.php, and since the theme customizer calls it specifically by name, I cannot simply add a new function, and I cannot override it using the same function name.

My best guess is that I need to somehow remove this function from the parent functions.php before loading a new function of the same name in my child function.php, but I cannot seem to figure out how.

Below is the code from the template file where the function is loaded into the template:

```
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++)
    if (get_theme_mod('flaxseedpro_fa_'.$i) != 'none') {
        flaxseedpro_display_featured_area( 
            get_theme_mod('flaxseedpro_fa_'.$i), 
            get_theme_mod('flaxseedpro_fa_title'.$i), 
            get_theme_mod('flaxseedpro_fa_cat'.$i)
        );
    }   
?>
```

Here, the $i variable is the value that is set in the Theme > Customizer screen. This file and code *could* be modified easily as a part of the child theme.

Below are two code snips from the parent functions.php which select the appropriate featured area code:

```
function flaxseedpro_display_featured_area($style, $fa_title, $cat) {
    if (is_home()) :
        switch ($style) {
            case 'carousel':
                flaxseedpro_carousel($fa_title, $cat);
                break;
            case 'style1':
                flaxseedpro_featured_style1($fa_title, $cat);
                break;
            case 'style2':
                flaxseedpro_featured_style2($fa_title, $cat);
                break;
            case 'style3':
                flaxseedpro_featured_style3($fa_title, $cat);
                break;
            case 'style4':
                flaxseedpro_featured_style4($fa_title, $cat);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    endif;
}
```

which leads to several functions such as this:

```
function flaxseedpro_featured_style2($fa_title, $cat) {
    ?>
    <div class="featured-style1 featured-style2">
        <?php if ('' !== $fa_title) : ?>
            <h2 class="featured-section-title container">
                <?php echo esc_html($fa_title); ?>
            </h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="featured-posts-inner container">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'cat' => $cat,
            );
            $fa_posts = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($fa_posts->have_posts()) :
                $counter = 0;
                while ($fa_posts->have_posts()) :
                    $fa_posts->the_post();
                    $counter++;
                    if (1 === $counter) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="feat-col1 md-6 sm-6">
                            <div class="md-12 pr-0 pl-0">
                                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('featured-post-item'); ?>>
                                    <div class="item-container mb-3">
                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>    
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-large', array('class' => 'featured-post-thumbnail-primary')); ?></a>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png'); ?>"></a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="post-title-parent">
                                        <a class="post-title title-font" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        <div class="post-author">
                                            <?php esc_html_e('By', 'flaxseed-pro'); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author()); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="entry-excerpt body-font mb-3"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="theme-button"><?php _e('Read More','flaxseed-pro') ?></a>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <div class="feat-col2 md-6 sm-6">
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('featured-post-item'); ?>>
                                <div class="md-4 xs-4">
                                    <div class="item-container">
                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>    
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'featured-post-thumbnail-secondary')); ?></a>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placeholder.png'); ?>"></a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="md-8 xs-8">
                                    <div class="post-title-parent">
                                        <a class="post-title title-font" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        <br><small><?php esc_html_e('By', 'flaxseed-pro'); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))); ?>" class="url fn n" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author()); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

This is the the code I've been trying to override but unable to find a solution as a part of the child theme. All of the answers I've found seem to require a hook, which I cannot discern from this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.

I changed the function name that is called in my template file (flaxseedpro_display_featured_area  >> flaxseedpro_display_featured_area2), then redefined the switch function to replace 'style3' with a new 'style5'. Then added the new 'style5' function with updated CSS code.